# Make flycheck mode respect flake8 config and warn for long lines

Tags: python, flycheck

I use `flycheck-mode` as my syntax checker/linter for Python. It works great for the most part, however I can't get it to warn me when I have gone over a specified line length.

I am using `flake8` as my checker for Python, and have confirmed this with `flycheck-verify-setup`. The output from this command in a `python-mode` buffer is:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer config.py in python-mode:

python-flake8
- predicate:  t
- executable: Found at /usr/bin/flake8

python-pylint
- predicate:  nil
- executable: Not found

python-pycompile
- predicate:  t
- executable: Found at /usr/bin/python

The following checker is explicitly selected for this buffer:

python-flake8
- major mode: `python-mode' supported
- predicate:  t
- executable: Found at /usr/bin/flake8

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled
checkers.
```

The checking works in general, so if I have the following Python code:

```
import re
long_string = "foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
class Foo():
    pass
```

I get two warnings from `flycheck`:

```
're' imported but unused [F401]
expected 2 blank lines, found 0 [E302]
```

I do not, however, get a warning that `long_string` is too long. I have tried setting:

```
(setq-default flycheck-flake8-maximum-line-length 79)
```

in my init file as suggested [here](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/378). I have tried configuring `flake8` with a `flake8` file in my `~/.config/` directory, as described [here](http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#global), which I assume `flycheck` is supposed to respect, based on [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18889/8430). I have also tried setting the value of `flycheck-flake8rc` to point to that `flake8` file. I have tried using a local configuration file within a project as described [here](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/721). None of these have worked for me. Instead, `flycheck` seems to ignore any `flake8` config I try to give it, and will not warn about line length. This is the case even when I use `emacs -Q`, initialize packages, and enable `global-flycheck-mode` - although, in this case the output of `flycheck-verify-setup` is the same. Any suggestions how I might be able to:

1. Get `flycheck-mode` to respect my `flake8` configuration file?
2. Get `flycheck-mode` to warn me about going over a specified line length?

Question 2 would be solved, in theory, by any solution to question 1, because I could set, e.g.:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 79
```

in my configuration file, but I would be satisfied with a solution to question 2 alone. Thank you!

Comment: Can you run `C-c ! C-c python-flake8` to check how Flycheck invokes `flake8` in an affected buffer?

Comment: Besides, please note that you can just use `setq` for the line length option and that it's `flycheck-flake8rc` (note the dash).

Comment: @lunaryorn thanks for the suggestions and catching my typo. Actually, I got the suggestion to use `setq-default` from your comment on this issue: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/378. I tried `setq` as well, and it didn't make a difference. Also, you suggestion to run `C-c ! C-c python-flake8` brought something very interesting to my attention: this command still doesn't warn about lines that are too long, but it shows the command being run as `flake8 --format\=default --max-line-length 79 - < /tmp/test.py`, so it seems like it is checking line length. Does this illuminate things?

Comment: That comment was over two years ago… things change, please don't dig too far in the past.  The issue lies elsewhere, and not with Flycheck as it seems.  I can't reproduce it;  if I run Flycheck with flake8 over your code sample I see a warning about the line being too long.  What's your flake8 version?

Comment: @lunaryorn my `flake8` version is `2.5.4`. But you are right, it seems like the issue is independent of `flycheck` and even Emacs, since using `flake8` from the command line outside of Emacs also doesn't expose the line length issue...I will do some more investigating now that I have this new information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see a warning with this version.   What are the versions of flake8's dependencies, i.e. the full output of `flake8 --version`?

Comment: The full output is: `2.5.4 (pep8: 1.7.0, mccabe: 0.2.1, pyflakes: 1.1.0) CPython 2.7.11+ on Linux`

Comment: How did you install flake8 with pyflakes **1.1**?  flake 2.5.4 [requires a lower version of pyflakes](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/blob/e2d6f33151f42245c038ca55b53bc0dd199147f4/setup.py#L52).

Comment: @lunaryorn I installed flake8 through `apt` originally, and that version of pyflakes was installed automatically as a dependency. I tried removing that version of flake8 and installing it through `pip` and it installs the same version of pyflakes as a dependency. I removed that version of pyflakes and tried to install an older version, but keep getting a message that I `Successfully installed pyflakes-1.1.0`, even though the output says an older version is being downloaded. I will continue to look into this, and maybe post a question in SO to avoid dragging out this off-topic discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use flymake mode directly. But I use [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) which uses flymake internally and works well.

You can install using `M-x package-install elpy`.

Next time, when you open a python file, you will get a warning like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am a long time user of elpy and have quite a bit of affection for that package, but I have been giving [`anaconda-mode`](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode) a try for the last few weeks. That mode's strength compared to elpy (in my opinion) is it's simplicity and small feature set. However, that is also a weakness in this case I guess, because `anaconda-mode` doesn't have integrated syntax checking, so I am trying to supplement with `flycheck`. I admit that all the things I am complaining about in this question work fine for me with elpy.